# Converting DEM into areas of "flatness", with arbitrary fill/cut to area ratio?

Tags: raster, dem, open-source-gis, arcgis-platform

I want to find areas of relative "flatness" in a DEM.

How can I find flat areas?

I want to find a neighbourhood of contiguous cells that have an elevation variance that is within a certain tolerance threshold.

I can use the ESRI suite of tools, or any open source GIS.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you mean by your last sentence. Are you looking at flatness on a per-cell basis or over some neighborhood?

Comment: @scw Clarified question

Comment: I was wondering if anybody tried doing this with SAGA GIS. I see there is a "flat detection" module. Is that a good tool to use for this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a region of specific size and area:

1. As before, classify your cells by the slope.
2. Then do a [Region Group](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=region_group) on the raster. The count value will give you area values for the raster.
3. Then if you need regions of a certain width (ie, not something long and thin) run [Zonal Geometry](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=zonal_geometry) with the Thickness option, which will give you the radius of the largest circle that can be drawn within the zone.

Comment: Wow, that's great.  There is so much in ArcMap that I had no idea about!

Answer (score 4):

**This problem has many different solutions: it needs further restrictions.**  After all, by choosing *any* value within the range of elevations in the dataset, the contour for that value will be "flat" (and horizontal).  This probably is not the sought-for answer, but it is *an* answer and it's perfectly valid.  Moreover, among all possible answers, the contour lines will achieve *minimal* "elevation variance," so arguably they are the *best answers*--at least until additional criteria are specified.

Typically one restricts such searches to reasonably compact regions by asking that they be circular, rectangular, or perhaps by limiting their [tortuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortuosity).  Also, there are many possible definitions of "elevation variance," such as range, standard deviation, [IQR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range), [MAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation), etc.

As an example of what can easily be done, **suppose we want to find *circular* regions where the elevation range does not exceed some threshold.**  (This is useful for implementing local requirements which frequently say a plot of land cannot rise more than *z* feet over distance *x*.)  The calculation is dead simple: pick the radius you want to investigate and compute the **focal range** for a circular neighborhood of that radius.  *Every cell in the resulting grid whose value is within the elevation tolerance is the center of a "flat" circle.*

There are obvious variations: you can explore a range of radii to search for the largest possible such circle; you can use neighborhoods of different shapes (such as square neighborhoods or even irregular neighborhoods); you can compute focal standard deviations instead of focal ranges.  I believe all these options have been discussed at one time or another on the [old ESRI forums](http://forums.esri.com/).

**One *huge* advantage this approach has over a slope-based solution** is that it is immune to the small measurement errors that afflict almost all DEMs.  Consider, for example, a DEM that was computed from a contour map.  Unless the DEM processing was *extremely* well done, it will still show terrace-like artifacts near the former contour lines.  At those cells, computed slopes can be extreme (but erroneous).  This won't materially affect the elevation-based focal stats technique but it will cause slope-based techniques to give the wrong, or inferior, results.

Comment: Just wondering: If you didn't have a tolerance in mind and just wanted to see how varied or 'flat' the elevation values where within the area, could you use a focal standard deviation instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to first calculate slope, as om_henners has mentioned, then use a focal operator to collapse the result down to the scale you're interested in. I'd recommend using [FocalMean](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=focalmean), where the neighborhood size matches the scale of 'flat' areas you're interested in. So for example, if you had a raster of 10m resolution, a 5x5 neighborhood would give you the average slope over 2.5 km<sup>2</sup> area.

The same analysis could be done in GRASS, with [r.mfilter](http://grass.itc.it/grass64/manuals/html64_user/r.mfilter.html).

Comment: Interesting approach.  Or I suspect I could use `FocalStd` directly on the DEM itself.  Either way, what if I do not want to find only areas of a particular geometry and size?  That is, I want areas that maximise the shape and size while fitting within the constraints.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you might be very interested in the techniques mentioned in this paper:
Gallant, J.C., Dowling, T.I. (2003): 'A multiresolution index of valley bottom flatness for mapping depositional areas', Water Resources Research, 39/12:1347-1359
and implemented in SAGA GIS: 
http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_modules_doc/ta_morphometry/ta_morphometry_08.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Spatial Analyst you could use [Slope](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Slope) instead of cut/fill.

1. Calculate the slope raster
2. Calculate your tolerance based on the maximum rate of change (see the formula on [How Slope Works](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=How%20Slope%20works) page)
3. Do a [setnull](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Set_Null) so that it sets the raster null where the slope values are greater than the tolerance; eg setnull(slope > tolerance, original_values)

Comment: Alternately use Fill (http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Fill) with the Z limit to your toleerance, calculate slope on the filled dataset and setnull all areas where slope is not 0.

Comment: Or less than a tolerated slope...

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  I am looking for a neighbourhood measure, not for individual cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Landserf](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~jwo/landserf/).

There is a tool to compute slope maps:

(flat areas are in yellow)

[image: Landserf slope map]

See section 1.6 of the [user guide](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~jwo/landserf/landserf230/doc/landserfManual.pdf).

An other possibility is to triangulate your DEM and compute the triangle's slopes.

Comment: triangulation might work...